# How does Facebook react when someone denies permission to a resource?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using the below code for my app. If I deny the permission, I am still able to access the app, but it should not take me to app right?

Where am I going wrong?

```
 //Facebook Authentication part 
   $user       = $facebook->getUser();

   $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,read_stream',

    )
 );
  $me = null; 
 // Session based API call.
  if ($session) {
try {
  $uid = $facebook->getUser();
 $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
   error_log($e);
 }
 }


  if (!$user) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
exit;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure this will give you the answer you are looking for. But I just wonder if you are aware of the expected authentication flow of a Facebook application.

When the "Don't Allow" is selected then the Facebook dialog box will redirect to:

```
http://YOUR_URL?error_reason=user_denied&
 error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.
```

Where YOUR_URL is the redirect_uri paramater that was specified in the oauth dialog URL.

Check out [Facebook Authentication Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Comment: :If you see zynga games,if you deny access,it takes to page says that user has denied but i know what facebook does.Ho do i do like zynga one?

Comment: You specify a redirect URI, at that URI check for the error_reason parameter. Then provide the content you want. Zynga haven't done anything magical..

Answer (score 0):

I think if you click on Dont Allow button it will take you to the app page, but if you handled the don't allow action in your code then you can redirect it to anywhere you want